# JPA @Version with Embedded Class

Tags: jpa, annotations, version

I have the below classes defined,

```
@Entity
@Idclass(Key.class)
public void ClassA {

...

@Id
@Version
private long version;

...
}

public class Key {
 ...
 private long version;
 ...
}
```

When compiling i get the below error,

"Unable to define @Version on an embedded class"

So is it possible to have a property which is part of the composite key defined as above also have the @Version. I did try adding the @version to the property in the Id class itself, but still it didn't work.

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense. The point of `@Version` is to define a field that the JPA engine will increment at each modification of the entity. The point of `@Id` is to define the primary key, which should be unique and immutable, and be used to identify an entity for its whole life. The `@Version` field should thus not be part of an ID.

Comment: thx for the clarification. I am using the version field in a different way, a new entity will be created for every update, hence it makes sense not to make the version annotated with @Version.